# Почему PDO не хочет воспринимать данные с массива?

Tags: php

```
$sql = "select a.id_feature_value, a.value, b.id_feature 
        from ps_feature_value_lang as a
        join ps_feature_value as b on a.id_feature_value = b.id_feature_value
        where a.value = :mass_name and a.id_lang = 1 and b.id_feature = :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(
        [
           ':mass_name' => (string)$name[$o],
           ':id'        => (int)$result['id_feature']
        ]
    );

   $r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Основной вопрос почему при привязке обычного массива созданного в файле (в том же  что и код) срабатывает все хорошо , т.е. передается правильное значение, а в том случае кода мы получаем массив через $name = file('f.txt') находит только последний элемент в списке

Comment: Понятность текста: 15%. Пожалуйста, сделайте так, чтобы неознакомленный пользователь мог легко понять суть проблемы.

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что вы берете `$name[$o]` в кавычки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что эта детская проблема не имеет отношения к PDO.

А причиной этого вопроса, как и половины других вопросов на СО, является **отсутствие минимальных навыков отладки** своего кода. К сожалению, пользователи ПХП, изучавшие этот язык по видеурокам, не имеют ни малейшего представления о таком процессе, как отладка, сиречь проверка всех входных условий.

Если бы автор позаботился о том, чтобы *проверить*, **что** содержится в переменной, которую он подставляет в запрос, и сделал бы это с помощью функции `var_dump()`, то он увидел бы очевидную вещь - что каждая содержит **перевод строки**, честно считываемый из файла функцией `file()`, если ей не задать соответствующий параметр.

Кстати, если `prepare()` выполняется внутри цикла, то это еще одно непонимание PDO, а именно смысла *подготовленных* выражений. Которые подготавливаются **один** раз, а потом только выполняются.

```
$names = file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$sql = "select a.id_feature_value, a.value, b.id_feature 
        from ps_feature_value_lang as a
        join ps_feature_value as b on a.id_feature_value = b.id_feature_value
        where a.value = :name and a.id_lang = 1 and b.id_feature = :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach ($names as $name)
{
    $stmt->execute(['name' => $name, 'id' => $result['id_feature']]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```